# Add Views programmatically to LinearLayout after it got inflated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, layout-inflater, android-popupwindow

I want to add some LinearLayouts to an existing Linearlayout.

The xml of the Activity looks as followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popupLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPopUp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The code of the Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Point p;
    private PopupWindow popup;
    private LinearLayout myLInearLayout;
    private TextView valueTV;
    private Button valueB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button popUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.open);
        popUpButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (p != null)
                    showPopup(MainActivity.this, p);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        int[] location = new int[2];
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.open);

        button.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        // Initialize the Point with x, and y positions
        p = new Point();
        p.x = location[0];
        p.y = location[1];

    }

    // The method that displays the popup.

    private void showPopup(final Activity context, Point p) {

        Rect rectgle = new Rect();
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);

        int popupWidth = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int popupHeight = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / 4;

        // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
        LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context
                .findViewById(R.id.popupLinearLayout);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, viewGroup);

        // Creating the PopupWindow
        popup = new PopupWindow(context);
        popup.setContentView(layout);
        popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
        popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
        popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popup.setFocusable(true);
        popup.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupWindowAnimation);

        // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down,
        // relative to button's position.

        int OFFSET_X = 0;
        int OFFSET_Y = 0;

        // Clear the default translucent background
        popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

        // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
        popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y
                + OFFSET_Y);

        // add LInearLayout
        myLInearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_horizontal);

        // add LayoutParams
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        myLInearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        // add textView
        valueTV = new TextView(this);
        valueTV.setText("The developer world is yours");
        valueTV.setId(5);
        valueTV.setLayoutParams(params);

        // add Button
        valueB = new Button(this);
        valueB.setText("thedeveloperworldisyours");
        valueB.setId(5);

        // add the textView and the Button to LinearLayout
        myLInearLayout.addView(valueTV);
        myLInearLayout.addView(valueB);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (popup != null && popup.isShowing()) {
            popup.dismiss();
            popup = null;
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

As you can see I want to add a Button and a TextView after I inflate a View and show it with an Animation in a PopupWindow. I would like to add some Views to the LinearLayout inside the ScrollView. This is for testing purposes, later I want to Add full LinearLayouts to the LinearLayout inside the ScrollView.
The Animation works perfectly. I just can't add some Views programmatically. Everything I get is a NullPointerException in the Line where I try to add the views.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. I just had to inflate the popup.xml to be able to get a reference to the LinearLayout I wanted to customize.

Here is the code if someone is facing the same problem:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Point p;
    private PopupWindow popup;
    private Button popUpButton;
    private TextView valueTV;
    private Button valueB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        popUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.open);
        popUpButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (p != null)
                    showPopup(MainActivity.this, p);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        int[] location = new int[2];
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.open);

        button.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        // Initialize the Point with x, and y positions
        p = new Point();
        p.x = location[0];
        p.y = location[1];

    }

    // The method that displays the popup.

    private void showPopup(final Activity context, Point p) {

        Rect rectgle = new Rect();
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);

        int popupWidth = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int popupHeight = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / 4;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);
        ViewGroup dlgView = (ViewGroup) contentView
                .findViewById(R.id.ll_horizontal);

        // Creating the PopupWindow
        popup = new PopupWindow(context);
        popup.setContentView(contentView);
        popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
        popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
        popup.setFocusable(true);
        popup.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupWindowAnimation);

        // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down,
        // relative to button's position.

        int OFFSET_X = 0;
        int OFFSET_Y = 0;

        // Clear the default translucent background
        popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

        // add textView
        valueTV = new TextView(this);
        valueTV.setText("The developer world is yours");
        valueTV.setId(5);

        // add Button
        valueB = new Button(this);
        valueB.setText("thedeveloperworldisyours");
        valueB.setId(5);

        // add the textView and the Button to LinearLayout
        dlgView.addView(valueTV);
        dlgView.addView(valueB);

        // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
        popup.showAtLocation(popUpButton, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X,
                p.y + OFFSET_Y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button popUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.open);
        int[] location = new int[2];
        popUpButton.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        // Initialize the Point with x, and y positions
        p = new Point();
        p.x = location[0];
        p.y = location[1];
        popUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (p != null)
                    showPopup(p);
            }
        });

    }

    // The method that displays the popup_layout.

    private void showPopup(Point p) {

        Rect rectgle = new Rect();
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);

        int popupWidth = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int popupHeight = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / 4;

        // Inflate the popup_layout.xml

        LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.popupLinearLayout);
        View layout = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, viewGroup);

        // Creating the PopupWindow
        popup = new PopupWindow(this);
        popup.setContentView(layout);
        popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
        popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
        popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popup.setFocusable(true);

       // popup.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupWindowAnimation);

        // Some offset to align the popup_layout a bit to the right, and a bit down,
        // relative to button's position.

        int OFFSET_X = 0;
        int OFFSET_Y = 0;

        // Clear the default translucent background
        popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

        // Displaying the popup_layout at the specified location, + offsets.
        popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);

        // add LInearLayout
        myLInearLayout = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.ll_horizontal);

        // add LayoutParams
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        myLInearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        // add textView
        valueTV = new TextView(this);
        valueTV.setText("The developer world is yours");
        valueTV.setId(5);
        valueTV.setLayoutParams(params);

        // add Button
        valueB = new Button(this);
        valueB.setText("thedeveloperworldisyours");
        valueB.setId(5);

        // add the textView and the Button to LinearLayout
        myLInearLayout.addView(valueTV);
        myLInearLayout.addView(valueB);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion! I've just tried this. But unfortunately it doesn't help me. :/
As far as I can see you just changed the initialization of the Point-Object. But I get the NullPointerException as soon as I try to work with the LinearLayout. In this line for example:

myLInearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);